# Element androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout must be declared

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, androidx, drawerlayout

I'm trying to use drawerlayout in my android applications. 
but it shows that the Element androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout must be declared .

my gradle (module:app)

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.40.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
}
```

thanks

Comment: Which file is showing that error? And which folder is it in, exactly?

Comment: in the activity xml : when i use the tag androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout it shows an error that it's not declared

Comment: Which folder is that file in?

Comment: Styles are to be found in `res/values*/` folders. Do you have a `<style>` with `name="ToolBarStyle"` somewhere in there? Usually find in files called `styles.xml`.

Comment: your question was so helpful , i was using the res/menu directory instead of layout . it works now thank you

Comment: No problem. We try to keep it to one problem per question, here, which is why I went ahead and closed this for your original "element...must be declared" issue. If you're still having problems with the style, though, please feel free to post a new question for that. Glad you got it figured out. Cheers!